# How to create a new database schema in SQL Express and give access to any user account of the current machine?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Mixed Mode / SQL Authentication is disabled.

Only Windows Authentication is available.

A database/schema has been created in the default instance (.\SQLEXPRESS) and is named "MyDatabase".

Using a SQL script that will be run by an administrator using the command line interface, I want to give **full access** to every user account of the machine (excluding guest account) to that schema.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to tell the SQL Server to allow everything to be able to log into the server.

```
CREATE LOGON [YourMachine\Users] FROM WINDOWS;
GO
```

Then go into the database and setup a user based on that login.

```
Use YourDatabase
GO
CREATE USER [YourMachine\Users] FOR LOGIN [YourMachine\Users]
GO
```

Then you can add the new user to the dbo role.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename='dbo', @membername='YourMachine\Users'
GO
```

All together the script will look something like this.

```
CREATE LOGON [YourMachine\Users] FROM WINDOWS;
GO
Use YourDatabase
GO
CREATE USER [YourMachine\Users] FOR LOGIN [YourMachine\Users]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename='dbo', @membername='YourMachine\Users'
GO
```

Just change YourMachine to be your computer's name and Yourdatabase to be your database name.

Comment: can I replace YourMachine by . ?

Comment: Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Windows NT user or group 'PC144\Users' not found. Check the name again.
Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Windows NT user or group 'PC144\Users' not found. Check the name again.
Msg 15014, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 36
The role 'dbo' does not exist in the current database.

Comment: No, you can't use ".".  Check to make sure that the local group Users does exist.  It might have been renamed.